# .NET Core Invoke Async View Twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I'm working on .NET Core 3.1 for the first time and would like to use best practice.

I am including a partial view in the layout called sidebar and within the sidebar I want 2 blocks of adverts, see (Adverts View Component).

If I try to invoke the view twice I only get the first view although the controller and view fire twice as expected.

Is this expected behavior? If so, what is the best way for me to achieve my desired result?

For this I have the following:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="col-4 float-left sidebar">
    <partial name="Components/Sidebar/Default.cshtml" /> <!-- Include the sidebar -->
</div>
```

Sidebar View

```
<!-- ADVERTS -->
<div class="container mt-4 p-0">
    <div class="row g-1">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Adverts", new { Id = 3, Amount = 2 }) <!-- Get 2 random adverts from the gold package adverts -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END ADVERTS -->
<!-- START CONTENT -->
<h2 class="fooddrink mt-4">Title Here</h2>
<p>Content Here</p>
<!-- END CONTENT -->
<!-- ADVERTS -->
<div class="container mt-4 p-0">
    <div class="row g-1">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Adverts", new { Id = 2, Amount = 2 }); <!-- Get 2 random adverts from the silver package adverts -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END ADVERTS -->
```

AdvertsViewComponent.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Fetch an amount of adverts invoked from a ViewComponent
    /// </summary>
    public class AdvertsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly horwichadmin_dbContext _context;

        public AdvertsViewComponent(horwichadmin_dbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a list of randomized Adverts.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The ID of the selected package.</param>
        /// <param name="amount">The amount of adverts to get.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a list of randomized adverts.</returns>
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int id, int amount)
        {
            using (_context)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();

                var randomAdverts = (await _context.AppAds
                        .Where(a => 
                                a.Package == id && 
                                a.Active == 1 && 
                                a.Start <= DateTime.Now && 
                                a.End >= DateTime.Now)
                        .ToListAsync())
                        .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());

                return View(randomAdverts.Take(amount));
            }
        }
    }
```

Adverts View Component

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.AppAds>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col">
        <img src="@Resources.Views.Shared._Layout.SiteUrl/images/ads/@item.Img" class="container-fluid" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: So, if you debug your code you see your code described in InvokeAsync being called twice or only one time?

Comment: After a weekend off, it turns out there were no items in the database existing with the requested ID sent to the ViewComponent. Amazing how coming away from something and coming back to it with fresh eyes can work.

Comment: @ScottC Do you mean you have found out the reason, and have solved the problem, right?

Comment: @ScottC A good night of sleep and a fresh mind are good allies of a programmer ;)

Comment: @Zhi Lv yes the output I got was correct, the second query returned no items. I was expecting it to return items from the database but non existed.